# Regression testing between test and dev environments for 1000s or URLs?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, google-chrome-devtools, integration-testing

I need to provide assurance over changes made to a site with 1000s of URLs.

What is the easiest way to do regression testing between a live and dev environment with the following structure?

```
 e.g.
 www.website.com/unique_web_page.html
 dev.website.com/unique_web_page.html
```

Need to do visual regression testing and capture any Javascript errors in console and any 404 assets.

Is there a third party tool that will do this that can be recommended? SAAS online?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand that you don't need any of the  usual tools (e.g. Selenium), I would suggest to take a look at [jsoup](https://jsoup.org). The tool

> provides a very convenient API for extracting and manipulating data, using the best of DOM, CSS, and jquery-like methods.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245519/handling-connection-errors-and-jsoup) discusses how to deal with status codes.

As for visual validations you can turn to [galen](http://galenframework.com) framework. It offers good syntax of checking the look and feel of the sites.

Comment: I checked out the link and it doesn't do the visual regression testing or record Javascript errors.

Comment: Ah I misunderstood what you need, so I updated my answer. Hope this time will be more of a help.

Comment: Thanks for the update but none of those seem to capture javascript error messages and the console